# In jQuery, Check for a class within .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I'm working with an SVG map. Within each  element of the map, I can hover to reveal a tooltip, or click to reveal a full popover.

If a popover is revealed, I would like to prevent the tooltip on hover. 
Currently, clicking a  also assigns a class of "selected." I would like to check for the presence of "selected" on a rect, and if not found, to display the tooltip.

Here's the code I'd like to use to do that:

```
Map.init = function() {

jQuery.get('resources.json', function(resources) {
    Map.resources = resources;
    $('#map').load('map.svg', function() {
        $('svg').svg();
        var svg = $('svg').svg('get');
        if (!$('rect').hasClass("selected")) {
            $('rect').hover(Map.tooltip);
        }
        $('rect').click(Map.popup);
        $('#map').click(Map.popdown);
    });
});
};
```

Here are the functions called above:

```
Map = {};

Map.popup = function(e) {
    var rect = $(this);

    /* Get position and dimensions */
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var rectWidth = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
    var rectHeight = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;

    /* Position popover */
    var centerX = offset.left + rectWidth/2 - 250;
    var centerY = offset.top + rectHeight/2;

    $('.popup').css({
        'top' : centerY,
        'left' : centerX,
    });

    /* Hide tooltip that pops up on hover */
    $('.tooltip').hide();

    /* Assign JSON data and show */
    var resource = Map.resources[rect.attr('id')];

    $('.selected').attr('class', '');
    rect.attr('class', 'selected');

    $('.resourceName').html(resource.resourceName).attr('href', resource.resourceUrl);
    $('.popup-header').css('background-image', 'url("'+resource.imageUrl+'")');
    $('.resourceDescription').html(resource.resourceDescription);

    $('.orgName a').attr('href', resource.orgUrl);
    $('.orgName a').html(resource.orgName);
    $('.orgDescription').html(resource.orgDescription);

    $('.activityType').html(resource.locationType);
    $('.activityInterval').html(resource.instanceType);
    $('.activityExperience').html(resource.difficultyLevel);
    $('.activityAgeStart').html(resource.ageRangeStart);
    $('.activityAgeEnd').html(resource.ageRangeEnd);

    $('.cta a').attr('href', resource.resourceUrl);

    $('.popup').show();
    e.stopPropagation();
};

Map.popdown = function() {
    $('.popup').hide();
    rect.attr('class', '');
};

Map.tooltip = function(e) {
    var rect = $(this);

    /* Get position and dimensions */
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var rectWidth = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
    var rectHeight = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;

    /* Position Tooltip */
    var centerX = offset.left + rectWidth/2;
    var centerY = offset.top + rectHeight/2;

    $('.tooltip').css({
        'top' : centerY,
        'left' : centerX,
    });

    /* Assign JSON data and show*/
    var resource = Map.resources[rect.attr('id')];

    $('.tooltipResourceName').html(resource.resourceName).attr('href', resource.resourceUrl);
    $('.tooltip').show();
    e.stopPropagation();
};
```

I believe its an issue with the .load() being used to load the map, but I've been unable to diagnose so far. Any way to check a class-based conditional within .load()?

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the elements, not operate on them all at once.

```
$('rect').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("selected")) {
        $(this).hover(Map.tooltip);
    }
});
```

Or you could match the class in a selector:

```
$('rect:not(.selected)').hover(Map.tooltip);
```

Note that this isn't dynamic -- if the class changes, the tooltip won't follow it. For dynamic binding, use delegation:

```
$('svg').on('hover', 'rec:not(.selected)', Map.tooltip);
```

Comment: Thanks, @barmar. Sorry if it wasn't clear: I'm need to disable the tooltip on `<rect>` elements that **do** have the class "selected." If I should just be able to drop a `!` on that if statement within the .each()?